# Merge GUI tools for those new to merging

Tags: software-development, gui, version-control

The other day I had to do a rather icky merge. I tried it via the command line, but was so confused that I had to use a GUI tool.

I used `meld`, but it seems that there are others, like `kdiff3`. But `meld`, while shiny, was still a bit hard to use. Not too hard, though, but I expect there to be something more intuitive.

Which tools are out there that a newbie to merging will be able to use easily?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: And are you willing to pay (for instance, for Beyond Compare)?  If so, please state a budget. If not, please add the [tag:gratis] tag. please help us to help you.

Comment: @Manishearth,  re "*bit hard*"; needs elaboration. Also, what  budget , $, $$, or $$$?

Answer (score 16):

It depends on what you're used to.

I came to Git from a Perforce world and as such, found [P4Merge](https://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools) the best. It is free and [easy to setup with Git](https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372).

However, I soon found P4Merge limiting and quickly graduated to [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php), which is not free.

If you're new to merging, start simple and try P4Merge.

UPDATE: I have now stopped using Beyond Compare and use [KDiff3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/) instead. The only thing you need to use kdiff3 are the keyboard shortcuts.

The panels you see in a 3 way merge are numbered 1, 2 and 3 from left to right. 
To resolve a merge conflict by choosing the changes from panel 1, you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> again and it turns off the change from panel 1. If you want changes from panel 1, followed by panel 2, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. If you want them in the reverse order, you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. See where I'm going with this? Its incredibly simple.

Finally, you navigate between conflicts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd>. If you want to manually add in changes, you just type. That's it.

Finally, as a nice bonus, if you're using Git Extensions on Windows, it comes with built in support for KDiff3.

PS> Even if you like the command line, you can invoke a GUI using `git mergetool`

Comment: BeyondCompare is nice, and I use WinMerge where I don't have BeyondCompare available.

Comment: I still recommend Beyond Compare

Answer (score 4):

We use [Araxis Merge](https://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en) (available for Windows and OS X) and I like to think that the basics of the application itself are very easy to use, so I think it would fit your requirement of "a newbie to merging will be able to use easily".

Of course, it also costs 200 € per user. (Well spent IMHO.)

Answer (score 1):

I have been consulting as a software developer for *cough!`* decades now. In my experience, there are a few "industry standards", which we can assume means that multiple people, at multiple companies, agree on their superiority.

If you have particular "must have" features, please update your question to state them.

You do not state an operating system.

---

For Windows, the standard ***paid*** solution is [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/). There is a list of features [here](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php).

I have purchased a license, and this is my preferred tool.

[image]

---

For Windows, the standard ***free*** solution is [WinnMerge](http://winmerge.org/), although you can use KDiff3 and Meld, both of which I mention later. Sicne I don't know which features are important to you, I can only say that ore companies use WinMerge, and I prefer it to those two.
[image]

---

For Linux, you can use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) - list of features [here](http://meldmerge.org/features.html)
[image]

---

For Linux, you can also use [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) - list of features [here](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/features.html).

The choice is all yours. If you need more information, please update your question.

Answer (score -1):

[SublimeMerge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) is worth mentioning.

[image]

Price: $100 (Evaluate for free – no account, tracking, or time limits) nagware

supported OS: linux, win, mac

what features you like: 3 way merge, integrates with `git mergetool`

why you think it is user-friendly: it has all the same shortcuts as sublime

Comment: Could you please add more details? Price, supported OS, what features you like, why you think it is user-friendly, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Please see https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality